# Ajax: Как выполнить скрипт, загруженный XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Как выполнить скрипт, загруженный на страницу при помощи XMLHttpRequest?

Пытаюсь воспользоваться eval() - ничего не выходит.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var el = document.getElementById('order-window-cont').getElementsByTagName('script');
        var len = el.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            eval.call(window, el[i].innerHTML);
        }
        document.getElementById("order-window-cont").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var winHeight = $('#order-window-buy-box').height();
        var winWidth = $('#order-window-buy-box').width();
        var dialogTop = (bodyHeight / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
        var dialogLeft = (bodyWidth / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
        $('#order-window-buy-box').css({
            top: dialogTop,
            left: dialogLeft
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать это универсальное решение для аякс запросов. 
А свой код что в onreadystatechange вставь в отдельную функцию, и передавай её в качестве 
callback. 
Строчка для вызова запроса выглядит вот так:

```
post(elem, param); // param это объект, в котором содержаться данные для передачи на сервер.
```

А вот собственно используемая библиотечка. Я её немного поправил, удалил лишнее. Так что скорее всего подойдет.
Ну вообще в Jquery есть нормальные возможность чтобы делать аякс запросы.

```
// Создаем экземпляр xmlHttpRequest - это конструктор. 
    function _getHTTPObject() {
        //Использование ActiveXObject для IE
        if(typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined') {
            try {
                http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                    http = false;
                };
            };
        //Решение для нормальных браузеров
        } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            try {
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                http = false;
            };
        };
        return http;
    };
        // Приводим в порядок отправляемые параметры
    function _validQueryString(obj){
        var query = [];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj[key] == null || isFunction(obj[key])) continue;
            if (isArray(obj[key])) {
                for (var i = 0, c = 0, l = obj[key].length; i < l; ++i) {
                    if (obj[key][i] == null || isFunction(obj[key][i])) continue;
                    query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '[' + c + ']=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key][i]));
                    ++c;
                };
            } else {
                query.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
            };
        };
        query.sort();
        var result = query.join('&');
        return result;
    };
        // Получаем экземпляр xmlHttpRequest
    function _initHTTPObject() {
        return _getHTTPObject();
    };
        // POST фасад запроса
    function post(options) {
        _request("POST", options)
    };
        // GET фасад запроса
    function get(options) {
        _request("GET", options)
    };
        // Выполняем сам запрос
    function _request(type, options){
        /* 
        Вызывается пользователем для отправки запроса.
        Аргументы:
            type - GET или POST запросы
            options.url - URL по которому отправляется запрос. Добавляет все аргумены в ссылку - пример. 'get_user_info.php?id=2&name=Oleg'
            options.callback - Исполняемая функция, после получения данных.
            options.format - Тип возвращаемого значения для этой функции. Может быть 'xml','json' или 'text'. По умолчанию это:'text'.
        */
        if(options.async == 'undefined') {
            options.async = true;
        }
        //XMLHttpRequest создается при каждом запросе - чтобы избежать проблем с IE
        var http = _initHTTPObject();

        if(!http || !options.url || !options.query || !type) {
            return;
        };
        var query = (typeof(options.query) != 'string') ? _validQueryString(options.query) : options.query;

        if (http.overrideMimeType) {
            http.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        };
        if(!options.format) {
            options.format = "json";
            options.format = options.format.toLowerCase();
        };
        if (type == 'GET') {
            options.url = options.url+"?"+query;
        };

        http.open(type, options.url, options.async);
        if (type == 'POST') {
            http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            http.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        };

        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState == 4) {
                if(http.status == 200) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout)
                    var result = "";
                    if(http.responseText) {
                        result = http.responseText;
                    };
                    //Если возвращаемые данные в формате JSON, выполняем eval перед возвращением результата.
                    if(options.format.charAt(0) == "j") {
                        //Наличие спец. символов создает проблемы в IE
                        result = decodeURIComponent(result);
                        result = result.replace(/[\n\r]/g,"");
                        result = eval('('+result+')'); 
                    };
                    // Получаем данные callback
                    if(options.callback) {
                        options.callback(result);
                    };
                } else { 
                    //Если есть ошибка генерируем её
                    if(error) {
                        new Error(http.status);
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        http.send((type == 'GET') ? null : query);
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                http.abort();
        }, 10000);
    };
```